# How to export SQLite data to CSV file in Flutter app

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, export-to-csv

I am trying to achieve export to CSV from SQLite data of my Flutter app. I want to know an efficient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite_more/tree/master/sqflite_porter

alextekartik comments in https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/78

csv utils detail code https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite_more/blob/master/sqflite_porter/lib/utils/csv_utils.dart

```
var result = await db.query('MyTable');
var csv = mapListToCsv(result);
```

Comment: do you know a proper way of using sqflite_porter to export db to sql statements but I'm getting issues like below: 
No such table: sqlite_sequence in "SELECT * from sqlite_sequence"